# Display Month is row wise

Tags: mysql

In my warehouse project, I want to call mysql data and want to display record per month name as row wise.
Below is my mysql code

```
SELECT `Invoice_No`,
       `WH_Name`,
       SUM(`Balance`),
       `Material_Issue_Date` 
FROM `NEW_STOCK_TEMP`
```

and below is my current output

[image]

But I want to get output like below
[image]

Any suggestions to modify the code or what would be the best query to get output on same way?

thanks in advance for your support here.

Comment: *and below is my current output* I don't believe. You use SUM() without GROUP BY - so the whole data is treated as single group, and the query must return one output row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use case statement for every month of a year. If getting particular year data then use YEAR() or for few months then use between startdate and enddate. WH_name have been used in group by clause along with invoiceNo if same warehouse name for multiple invoices otherwise use MAX(WH_Name) in select clause and remove from group by clause.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT Invoice_No
     ,WH_Name
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Material_Issue_Date) = 1 THEN Balance END) jan
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Material_Issue_Date) = 2 THEN Balance END) feb
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Material_Issue_Date) = 3 THEN Balance END) mar
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Material_Issue_Date) = 4 THEN Balance END) apr
     ...
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Material_Issue_Date) = 12 THEN `Balance` END) dec
FROM NEW_STOCK_TEMP
WHERE YEAR(Material_Issue_Date) = 2021
GROUP BY Invoice_No
     ,WH_Name;
```

Comment: Hi @Ripon please check this above query and let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Buddy thanks a lot. the result is the same way that i am expecting. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi Rahul Buddy, Hope you are doing well and safe. I have solved my project per your above advice. Now there is an issue while I am getting output. If I choose "WHERE YEAR(Material_Issue_Date) = 2021" my pivot table is showing month wise issued data but the items not issued in 2021 not showing. in stock column. If I want to show non issued  items quantity too in this report in stock column even not issued on same year how to arrange code along with above output

Comment: As per your new requirement WHERE clause condition will moved in every case statement..like SUM(CASE when year = 2021 and month = 1 then Balance end)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT `Invoice_No`,
   `WH_Name`,
   (SELECT SUM(`Balance`) FROM NEW_STOCK_TEMP where Material_Issue_Date='January') AS January, (SELECT SUM(`Balance`) FROM NEW_STOCK_TEMP where Material_Issue_Date='February') AS February
    FROM `NEW_STOCK_TEMP`
```

Comment: Hi Mitun, Buddy, thanks a lot. Month name by colume wise is notw visible but value is showing null under month name by invoice.

Comment: you have to pass the month name,date appropriately according to your column value